# When were the Shards of Magnus first mentioned?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

I have been reading through the Horus Heresy, and after the attack on Prospero we learn that Magnus was shattered into shards. I know that other Black Library books set in the 41st millennium+ have also explored these shards of Magnus, but my question is:

When did the Black Library/Games Workshop source material first mention that Magnus was shattered into Shards? Was it an idea that was first shown in the Horus Heresy series, or had it been shown earlier then it appeared in the heresy books? Has it always been part of the story of Magnus?

Comment: Prospero Burn was released in 2009, so you're looking for a book that mentions the Shards of Magnus that was released prior to 2009?

Comment: I don't think the shards where actually mentioned in prospero Burns, if I am right I think its when the whitescars traveled to the ruins of Prospero and the Khan found the first shard. But it is around that time. Basicly are the shards a modern idea created by heresy authors, or a longstanding plotline.

Comment: They were created to give Ahriman something to do. He needed motivation and a possible end goal. Like _If I find the shards, I can resurrect Magnus._ I've only ever read about them in his stories. So if they're not mentioned in Prospero Burns, I'd guess we only hear of them after Ahriman's line of novels starts 2013 and never before.

Comment: @Daft: isn't "finding the Eldar's Black Library" Ahriman's goal? Are these two plotlines connected?

Comment: @Taladris he can have multiple goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Very probably in Ahriman's line of novels

The only character in 40k that really cares about the Shards of Magnus is [Ahriman](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Ahzek_Ahriman) and his [line of novels](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Ahriman_(Novel_Series)) began in 2013. That's probably the first time we ever hear about them. No one has any reason to mention them prior to that.